# Fetch date and convert format using laravel 5.2 eloquent query & carbon

Tags: php, laravel, date, laravel-5, php-carbon

I have controller code which fetches some rows from table and passes those to views, below is the sample result fetched by code

[image]

In above image you can check there is show_date and format is Y-m-d , Now I am displaying this date in view as it is currently , but i want to convert this date format to something like this

```
 21 Sep 2016 ,Wed
```

My controller code is

```
 public function show($id)
{
    $cities=General_cities::pluck('city_name','city_id');
    $showtime=Movies_showtimes::with('showdata','movie','cinema')->where([['cinema_id','=',$id],['show_date','>=',Carbon::today()],])->orderBy('show_date', 'asc')->get();

    $cinemahall=Movies_cinemahall::where('cinema_id',$id)->get();
    return view('admin.viewshowtime',compact('cities','showtime','cinemahall'));
}
```

I am little confused how can i update the eloquent object's all show_date in bulk i.e It should be done after getting eloquent object or It should be fired directly in db query or Is is better to covert date in View.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final answer which worked for this question, thanks to @camelCase and @Borna for figuring out the solution to this answer.

I used Laravel 5.2 accessor for this solution,  check here https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

This is the accessor code that i wrote in Model which converts dateformat fetched in eloquent collection.

```
 public function getShowdateAttribute($value)
{
    $carbon = new Carbon($value);
    return $carbon->format('j M Y, D'); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$dt = Carbon::today();
echo $dt->format('j F Y \\, l');
```

Answer (score 1):

While there are many approaches, I think handling in the `view` using Carbon's `format()` is a nice solution. See the [Carbon docs](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting) for further formatting methods.

While iterating over your collection, you can format `show_date` like:

```
$showTime->show_date->format('j M Y, D');
```

Note: for this to work, `show_date` must be a instance of Carbon. You can tell Eloquent to automatically do this by adding it in the [model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators). It would look something like this:

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'show_date'];
```